# Creating a menu using Grails

Tags: grails

How can I build a menu-like selection bar in Linux using Grails? Is there any plugin that can help do this?

Comment: Your "in Linux" requirement is a bit confusing - the two (Grails, Linux) are pretty much mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

This one?

*GrailsUI (GUI) is a plugin that provides an extensive tag library of rich ajax components based on the Yahoo! UI (YUI) JavaScript library and a YUI extension called the Bubbling Library. It has been designed for ease-of-use as well as configurability.*

http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui

Comment: I've used this plugin and been very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [the Grails Navigation plugin](http://www.grails.org/Navigation+plugin).